# How to wait to finish all the task in doOnNext before calling the doOnComplete?

Tags: android, rx-java2

just asking if I am doing it correct, because I don't know why the `doOnComplete` is calling while the `doOnNext` is not yet finish?

So that's why, I am asking on how to wait all the task inside the `doOnNext` 
before calling the `doOnComplete`?

The other task inside the `doOnNext` is the inserting of data into the database.

```
private val disposable = CompositeDisposable()

val branchUser : Observable<BranchUserResponse> = getApi().getBranchUser()
val areaUser : Observable<AreaUserResponse> = getApi().getAreaUser()
val regionalUser : Observable<RegionalUserResponse> = getApi().getRegionalUser()

disposable.add(
    Observable.merge(branchUser, areaUser, regionalUser)
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .doOnNext { it ->
            when (it) {
                is BranchUserResponse -> {
                    branchUserViewModel.addAll()
                        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                        .subscribe(
                            {
                                Log.i(TAG, "addAll success")
                                // the doOnComplete is already called before the Log here is call.
                                // Same with the other condition.
                                // What I want is to call this first before the doOnComplete or doFinally.
                            },
                            {
                                Log.e(TAG, "addAll failed", it)
                            }
                        )
                }
                is AreaUserResponse -> {
                    // some stuff here...
                }
                is RegionalUserResponse -> {
                    // some stuff here...
                }
            }
        }
        .doOnComplete {
            Log.i(TAG, "Complete")
        }
        .doFinally {
            Log.i(TAG, "Finally")
        }
        .subscribe()
)
```

Any help is appreciated, Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to do `rx-stuff` in all branches specified in `doOnNext` you have to change `doOnNext` to `flatMap`:

```
private val disposable = CompositeDisposable()

val branchUser : Observable<BranchUserResponse> = getApi().getBranchUser()
val areaUser : Observable<AreaUserResponse> = getApi().getAreaUser()
val regionalUser : Observable<RegionalUserResponse> = getApi().getRegionalUser()

disposable.add(
    Observable.merge(branchUser, areaUser, regionalUser)
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .flatMap { it ->
            when (it) {
                is BranchUserResponse -> {
                    branchUserViewModel.addAll()
                }
                is AreaUserResponse -> {
                    // some stuff here...
                }
                is RegionalUserResponse -> {
                    // some stuff here...
                }
            }
        }
        .doOnComplete {
            Log.i(TAG, "Complete")
        }
        .doFinally {
            Log.i(TAG, "Finally")
        }
        .subscribe()
)
```

Comment: Just note that the flatmap should return an `Observable`, so you should also delete the inner subscription.